# Recursive formulae in logic?

Tags: logic

Given domain $A$ and variables $x,y,z$, we could define the following "recursive formula":

$$\phi(x,y): \psi(x,y) \lor \exists z,[\phi(x,z)\land\phi (z,y)]\tag {*}$$
Where $\psi(x,y)$ is a first-order formula.
Clearly, this formula is not logically equivalent to any formula in first order logic (defined over the same domain). However, if we include into the domain of discourse the set $S^A:\mathbb N\to A$ of sequences over $A$, then I think we can restate it as: 
$$\phi(x,y):\exists s:S^A,\exists N,\forall n,[0<n<N\to \psi(s_n,s_{n+1})]$$

What is the status of a formula like $(*)$ ? Are recursive formula like this accepted  as legitimate by logicians/mathematicians? Is every such formula equivalent to a formula in second order logic or in first order logic with an expanded domain?

Comment: The two answer you have are complementary: Daniel's answer is telling you how your "definition" might be viewed as in a functional programming language and modelled in set theory or second-order logic; my answer is pointing out the first-order statement of the "definition" as an equivalence is completely anodyne, even though it does not capture the intension behind the definition. Your sentence beginning "Clearly" isn't actually very clear, which is why you've got two quite different answers. However, it's a good question and I hope you found the answers useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many such cases, at least in general mathematics (not in first-order logic, as you observed), such constructions come up often in practice.  In this case, it would typically be stated something like: let $\psi(x, y)$ be a relation on the universe $U$ of discourse.  Then we define $\phi(x, y)$ to be the smallest relation on $U$ such that $\psi(x, y) \rightarrow \phi(x, y)$ for all $x, y$, and such that $\phi(x, z) \wedge \phi(z, y) \rightarrow \phi(x, y)$ for all $x, y, z$.  (In this particular case, what you get is exactly what's called the *transitive closure* of $\psi$.)

One common way to define this $\phi$ is to take the intersection $\Phi_0$ of all subsets of $U \times U$ which contain $\{ (x, y) \mid \psi(x, y) \}$ and which are transitive, and then define $\phi(x, y)$ to mean $(x, y) \in \Phi_0$.  Another way to state this in a second-order logic type of language is: $$\phi(x, y) := \forall R, [(\forall a, b, \psi(a, b) \rightarrow R(a, b)) \wedge (\forall a, b, c, R(a, c) \wedge R(c, b) \rightarrow R(a, b))] \rightarrow R(x, y).$$
(Here $R$ ranges over all binary relations on the universe of discourse $U$.)

It might be interesting to note that the foundational system of Coq, Calculus of Constructions, treats "constructions" like this as being a fundamental object of the system.  For example, in Coq, you can define the transitive closure of a relation by:

```
Section TC.

Variables (A : Type) (R : A -> A -> Prop).

Inductive TC : A -> A -> Prop :=
| TC_base : forall x y : A, R x y -> TC x y
| TC_trans : forall x y z : A, TC x z -> TC z y -> TC x y.

End TC.
```

---

Do note, however, that there must be some restrictions on the types of such "recursive" definitions that are allowed, or you can easily run into contradictions.  For example, if you tried to recursively define $\phi$ as meaning $\lnot \phi$, then the only way $\phi$ could be true is if $\lnot \phi$ is true, so $\phi$ is also false and you get a contradiction.  On the other hand, if $\phi$ were false, then $\lnot \phi$ would be true, so by the recursive definition, this would imply $\phi$ would be true, again giving a contradiction.  (This example is very closely related to the "liar paradox".)

Usually, the cases where you can get a "recursive" definition like this to be valid and to act as expected would be where the conditions are of the type of specifying "generators" (e.g. $\psi(x, y) \rightarrow \phi(x, y)$) and "closure conditions" (e.g. $\phi(x, z) \wedge \phi(z, y) \rightarrow \phi(x, y)$).  And in some treatments, the "generators" type of condition will be treated as a special case of the "closure condition" type of condition but where there are no "input" hypotheses involving the condition you're defining, only the "output" involves it.

(In the case of Calculus of Constructions, the restriction which maintains consistency is a "strict positivity" syntactic restriction on where the object being defined is allowed to appear in the "input hypotheses".)

Answer (score 1):

First-order logic on its own is completely neutral about axioms that might be interpreted as recursive definitions: as a simple example, $\forall x(f(x) = f(x))$ is trivially true in any first-order theory even though it will lead to a non-terminating function if you treat it as a definition in a functional programming language.

In your example, if $\psi(x, y)$ is a formula in the language of a first-order theory $\cal T$, then there is no reason why we should not define a new theory $\cal T'$ that extends $\cal T$ by adding a new predicate symbol $\phi$ and a new axiom:

$$\forall x \forall y(\phi(x,y) \Leftrightarrow \psi(x,y) \lor \exists z[\phi(x,z)\land\phi (z,y)])$$

$\cal T'$ is consistent if $\cal T$ is: if you interpret $\phi(x, y)$ as identically true, you satisfy the new axiom.

Comment: Given the formula you've written down, we can have multiple interpretations of $\phi$ that satisfy the theory, right? that is, for any model $M_{\mathcal T}$ of $\mathcal T$, there are potentially multiple models $M_{\mathcal T'}$ that have $M_{\mathcal T}$ as a reduct?

Comment: @user56834: sure. E.g., if the domain of discourse is $\Bbb{N}$ and $\psi(x,y)$ is $y = x + 1$, $\phi(x, y)$ could be interpreted as $x < y$ or $x \le y$ or identically true or ... This is the point at which first-order logic starts to be a bit too weak to express recursive definitions properly: if you want to say $\phi$ is the smallest relation that satisfies the given condition, then you have to resort either to second-order logic or to special properties of the particular theory and the particular expansion that you want to define.

Comment: This is interesting, but I'm not sure if this is the same as what I intended with my formula. I intended it as literally *defining* a formula, one that can be "unrolled" the way recursive functions can be. When you "unroll" the formula that I intended to write down, you get my second formula which is defined in terms of sequences.

Comment: Your question says "what is the status of a formula like (*)?". What I am trying to explain is that it has no special status However, it doesn't deliver the meaning you intended: to get that meaning you need second-order logic or some kind of substitute for that, e.g., your proposal of adding sequences to the language.

Comment: I just re-read your comment to the main question, and I realized I misinterpreted it. I now understand it better and it makes sense. Thanks!